# JQUERY Save Caret After Text Replacement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm very new to JS/JQUERY, and have spend the last two days trying to figure this out.

I have the code below but when a user is typing it brings the caret back to the beginning of the DIV. I need the caret position to remain where the user last typed. I've seen lots of similar posts, but none seem to work with JQUERY... or maybe I'm not doing it right...(probably)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
  <meta name="googlebot" content="noindex, nofollow">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<title> TEST</title>

<style>
div.input1 
{
    background-color:#eee;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin:5px;
    width:750px;
    height:20px;
}
</style>


<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(window).load(function()
    {
        var wrapwords = function() 
        {
                $('#editor > div').each(function() 
            {
            //--------------------Problem is here------------------------
                var s=window.getSelection();
                var sr=s.getRangeAt(0);
                console.log("1",s.anchorOffset+" "+s.focusOffset,sr);


                    $(this).html($(this).text().replace(/\b(\w+)\b/g, "<span>$1</span>"));

                //s.removeAllRanges();
                //s.addRange(sr);
                console.log("2",s.anchorOffset+" "+s.focusOffset,sr);
            //--------------------Problem is here------------------------



                });

                $('#editor span').hover(function() 
            { 
                $('#word').text($(this).css('background-color','#ffff66').text()); 
            },
                function() 
            { 
                $('#word').text('');
                $(this).css('background-color','');

            });

        };

        $('#editor').on('keyup', function() 
        {
            wrapwords();
        });
});
</script>

<script type='text/javascript'>
//-------------------------------------------------Text Box Length Start------------------------------------
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        var excempt = [37,38,39,40,46,8,36,35];                                     // Excempt keys(arrows, del, backspace, home, end);

        $("[contenteditable='true']").each(function(index,elem)                     // Loop through every editiable thing
        {
                var $elem = $(elem);                                                // Check for a property called data-input-length="value" (<div contenteditiable="true" data-input-length="100">)
            var length = $elem.data('input-length');                            // Validation of value

                if(!isNaN(length))                                              // Register keydown handler
            {

                    $elem.on('keydown',function(evt)                            // If the key isn't excempt AND the text is longer than length stop the action.
                {
                        if(excempt.indexOf(evt.which) === -1 && $elem.text().length > length) 
                    {
                                evt.preventDefault();
                                return false;
                            }
                    });
                }
        });
    });
//-------------------------------------------------Text Box Length End---------------------------------------
</script>
<script>
  var update = function() {
    $('#caretposition').html(getCaretPosition(this));
  };
  $('#editable').on("mousedown mouseup keydown keyup", update);
</script>




</head>

<body>
<div contenteditable="true" class="input1" id="editor" data-input-length="100"><div> These are words</div></div><br>

Current word: <span id="word"></span>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: have you played with https://github.com/acdvorak/jquery.caret ?

Comment: Yes, I played with it. But I haven't had much luck getting it to suit my needs. The Sample code I found for it focuses on textareas and not divs, and I'm not fluent in JS/JQUERY enough to modify the code correctly. Do you have an example I should look at? - Thank you.

Comment: any reason you have to use a `contenteditable` div instead of a textarea/input?

Comment: Well there's a whole section of code removed... but basically JQUERY drop down context menus don't work with text areas very well. I have to use content editable.

However I do have an update on my problem.

Looks like the <SPANS> being put in the <DIV> are messing with the caret placement. The Caret placement is only allowing it to go between <DIV>-Caret-<SPAN> if I remove the <SPANS> it works fine... but I need the spans.... know of any way to get all nested items of a object IE <DIV><SPAN CHILD>WordS</SPAN CHILD><SPAN CHILD 2>words</SPAN CHILD2></DIV>

This is where Im at now

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working product. It probably could use some fine tuning but it functions.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
  <meta name="googlebot" content="noindex, nofollow">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<title>Test</title>

<style>
div.input1 
{
    background-color:#eee;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin:5px;
    width:750px;
    height:20px;
}
</style>


<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(window).load(function()
    {   

        //------------------Global Variables Start----------------------
        var saveSelection, restoreSelection;
        var divSelection;
        var editable = $("#editor")[0];
        var excempt = [37,38,39,40,46,8,36,35];
        //------------------Global Variables End------------------------ 


        //-------------------Highlight words Start----------------------Thank you: Grant Gibson (Stack Overflow)
        var wrapwords = function() 
        {
                $('#editor > div').each(function() 
            {
                    $(this).html($(this).text().replace(/\b(\w+)\b/g, "<span>$1</span>"));
                //console.log($(this).html());   //Words
                });

                $('#editor span').hover(function() 
            { 
                $('#word').text($(this).css('background-color','#ffff66').text());
                //console.log($('#word').text());     //Selected Word

            },
                function() 
            { 
                $('#word').text('');
                $(this).css('background-color','');

            });

        };
        $('#editor').on('keyup', function() 
        {
            divSelection = saveSelection(editable);
            wrapwords();
            restoreSelection(editable, divSelection);

        });
        wrapwords();
        //-------------------Highlight words End------------------------Thank you: Grant Gibson (Stack Overflow)
        //-------------------Save Cursor Position Start --------------- Thank you: Tim Down (Stack Overflow)
        if (window.getSelection && document.createRange) 
        {
                saveSelection = function(containerEl) 
            {
                    var doc = containerEl.ownerDocument, win = doc.defaultView;
                    var range = win.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
                    var preSelectionRange = range.cloneRange();
                    preSelectionRange.selectNodeContents(containerEl);
                    preSelectionRange.setEnd(range.startContainer, range.startOffset);
                    var start = preSelectionRange.toString().length;

                    return {
                            start: start,
                            end: start + range.toString().length
                    }
                };

                restoreSelection = function(containerEl, savedSel) 
            {
                    var doc = containerEl.ownerDocument, win = doc.defaultView;
                    var charIndex = 0, range = doc.createRange();
                    range.setStart(containerEl, 0);
                    range.collapse(true);
                    var nodeStack = [containerEl], node, foundStart = false, stop = false;

                    while (!stop && (node = nodeStack.pop())) 
                {
                            if (node.nodeType == 3) 
                    {
                                var nextCharIndex = charIndex + node.length;
                                if (!foundStart && savedSel.start >= charIndex && savedSel.start <= nextCharIndex) 
                        {
                                        range.setStart(node, savedSel.start - charIndex);
                                        foundStart = true;
                                }
                                if (foundStart && savedSel.end >= charIndex && savedSel.end <= nextCharIndex) 
                        {
                                        range.setEnd(node, savedSel.end - charIndex);
                                        stop = true;
                                }
                                charIndex = nextCharIndex;
                            } 
                    else 
                    {
                                var i = node.childNodes.length;
                                while (i--) 
                        {
                                        nodeStack.push(node.childNodes[i]);
                                }
                            }
                    }

                    var sel = win.getSelection();
                    sel.removeAllRanges();
                    sel.addRange(range);
                }
        } 
        else if (document.selection) 
        {
                saveSelection = function(containerEl) 
            {
                    var doc = containerEl.ownerDocument, win = doc.defaultView || doc.parentWindow;
                    var selectedTextRange = doc.selection.createRange();
                    var preSelectionTextRange = doc.body.createTextRange();
                    preSelectionTextRange.moveToElementText(containerEl);
                    preSelectionTextRange.setEndPoint("EndToStart", selectedTextRange);
                    var start = preSelectionTextRange.text.length;

                    return {
                            start: start,
                            end: start + selectedTextRange.text.length
                    }
                };

                restoreSelection = function(containerEl, savedSel) 
            {
                    var doc = containerEl.ownerDocument, win = doc.defaultView || doc.parentWindow;
                    var textRange = doc.body.createTextRange();
                    textRange.moveToElementText(containerEl);
                    textRange.collapse(true);
                    textRange.moveEnd("character", savedSel.end);
                    textRange.moveStart("character", savedSel.start);
                    textRange.select();
                };
        }
        //-------------------Save Cursor Position End --------------- Thank you: Tim Down (Stack Overflow)  
        //-------------------Max Text Length Start------------------- Thank you: Tschallacka (Stack Overflow)
        $("[contenteditable='true']").each(function(index,elem)                     // Loop through every editiable thing
        {
                var $elem = $(elem);                                                // Check for a property called data-input-length="value" (<div contenteditiable="true" data-input-length="100">)
            var length = $elem.data('input-length');                            // Validation of value

                if(!isNaN(length))                                              // Register keydown handler
            {

                    $elem.on('keydown',function(evt)                            // If the key isn't excempt AND the text is longer than length stop the action.
                {
                        if(excempt.indexOf(evt.which) === -1 && $elem.text().length > length) 
                    {
                                evt.preventDefault();
                                return false;
                            }
                    });
                }
        });
        //-------------------Max Text Length End------------------- Thank you: Tschallacka (Stack Overflow)
        //---------------------------------------------------------
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div contenteditable="true" class="input1" id="editor" data-input-length="120"><div id="main">
These are words
</div>
</div><br>
Current word: <span id="word"></span>


</body>
</html>
```